# Is my db-sync far behind the latest block/slot?

Tags: cardano-db-sync

Looking at the select statement in the screencap below - with the latest info also displayed from cardanoscan - I was expecting to see a direct correlation but my db-sync appears to be far behind cardanoscan? Am I querying the db incorrectly? Making an incorrect assumption or interpreting wrong, or has my db-sync simply fallen far behind?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should avoid using the `id` field in any query (even sorting) for any purpose other than joining tables. The `id` fields are auto-generated by
PostgreSQL and different instances can have different `id` fields for the same block. It would be better to sort on `block_no` (which increments by one for each new block) or `time`.

It looks like your instance is an epoch or so behind.

Comment: Thank you for responding, as well as the knowledge about record id's.

Comment: Only when I sort by time do I get the correct ordering now that I've tried, and in fact I see I am getting the latest block/slot after all..!